# Sl-slider doesn't work on safari

Tags: wordpress, safari, slider

i have a little problem with Sl-Slider in a Wordpress (http://www.apestreetfooding.it/). I set autoplay and navigator, in cross browsing goes perfectly except for Safari.

this is the Js:

$.Slitslider.defaults = {
        // transitions speed
        speed : 800,
        // if true the item's slices will also animate the opacity value
        optOpacity : false,
        // amount (%) to translate both slices - adjust as necessary
        translateFactor : 230,
        // maximum possible angle
        maxAngle : 25,
        // maximum possible scale
        maxScale : 2,
        // slideshow on / off
        autoplay : true,
        // keyboard navigation
        keyboard : true,
        // time between transitions
        interval : 4000,
        // callbacks
        onBeforeChange : function( slide, idx ) { return false; },
        onAfterChange : function( slide, idx ) { return false; }
    };

Comment: Would be better if you explain your problem neatly, You have to mention what is the error, what have you tried etc

Comment: I think the problem is the Javascript, because the bullet doesn't appear and the slider doesn't start. As said I tried to change the settings but I did not get any result